# Freezing Window install UEFI mode on a GPT Disk

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, uefi, gpt

I am trying to installing Create another dual boot system with Windows 7 and 10 on an MSI system (FM2-A75IA-E53) in full UEFI mode. Win10 on the 1st partition near the leading edge and Win7 on the next. I just found out that I may not have to install Windows 7 on the 1st partition and upgrade it. Was told I may be able to just install Win10 adn use the Win7 PK to activate it.

After I install Windows 10 via this method it appears that I will still have the issue of using my Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit OEM DVD to install Windows 7 in UEFI on a GPT disk on the 2nd partition.

Information on many sites say that installing in UEFI on a GPT disk is possible and that the needed EFI files to boot and install in this mode are on the dvd. However. after the files load and windows starts up the system always freezes right at the end of the red, blue, yellow, green graphic that forms the MS logo comes together just an instant before the display would normally go black for a second or two before you get the first install page to choose your language. Does anyone know the cause of the freezing windows installation?

Is there a workaround. I hear you can install Win7 in MBR (CSM) mode and then switch to UEFI but when I tried this and enabled the "Windows 8 Compatibility" the Windows 7 would not boot any longer.

I would be very grateful for a solution.

I ultimately want to upgrade this Windows 7 to Windows 10 and would like it to be a UEFI system. Or should I just scrap the whole Idea and go with MBR emulation type install with 'Windows 8 Compatibility' Disabled?

Comment: So basically what you were saying is that everyone that has ANY version (Retail or OEM) gets Windows 10 for free now  via using your PK? I will have to look that up since the research I did 12 hours agot got mixed results.

Comment: Apparently using the install key from 7 to install 10 *still* works on the current build, and once its activated you're good. However the 'official' free update period is over. TBH, the only real way is to see if the key works and it activates directly from windows 10 media.

Comment: That link you posted in chat imply that you don't need your PK and that it is a digital license activation.

Comment: That's *post* upgrade, and the MS supplied upgrade tool will simply refuse to work. Its a bit like a supermarket coupon. 30% off till december 25th, and its worthless paper on the 26th. This is *essentially* the only possible path to use your windows 7 licence to install 10, other than 'abusing' the assertive technologies loophole.

Comment: It also says, "You upgraded to Windows 10 for free from an eligible device running a genuine copy of Windows 7 or Windows 8.1." I didn't see anywhere that you can just enter a Win7 PK to activate Win10

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/266072/you-can-still-get-windows-10-for-free-with-a-windows-7-8-or-8.1-key/ see here.

Comment: Am I missing something. You said "The only way" but I didn't see a way here on that page. Ramhound said that I can enter my Windows 7 PK to activate Windows 10 after downloading and installing it and I don't have to use the assistive tech upgrade.

Comment: That's what that link says. - " Enter any Windows 7, 8, or 8.1 key that hasn’t previously been used to upgrade to 10, and Microsoft’s servers will give your PC’s hardware a new digital license that will allow you to continue using Windows 10 indefinitely on that PC"

Comment: I looked at some "How To Geek" pages this morning but missed that one. I hope this doesn mess up my plan to use the key on partition 1 for Windows 10 upgrade or install and on partition 2 for Windows 7 for dual booting. Early last year I did some work on a friends laptop and cloned his Win7 part. and installed it on a 2nd and upgraded the 2nd partition to Windows 10. Both of them booted fine without MS saying, "you already upgraded to Windows 10 with this PK, you can't use Windows 7 with this PK now.